# Replace yum with apt on CentOS 5?

Tags: centos, yum, apt

I used to have apt available on my CentOS server, but I had to reinstall and now I have yum. I've searched on how to replace it with no results.

If anyone could help, thanks!

I am on CentOS 5.9, if that helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it may be possible to run a version of `apt` on a CentOS server, I'd strongly urge you to use the native `yum` commands, as that's the packaging and software delivery framework for CentOS and other Red Hat-like operating systems.

This [apt and yum translation table](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwitchingToUbuntu/FromLinux/RedHatEnterpriseLinuxAndFedora#Package_Management) can help if you're looking for the proper command equivalents between the two.

However, [apt for CentOS](http://pkgs.repoforge.org/apt/) *does* exist. Here's a [Dag Wieers article](http://dag.wieers.com/blog/using-apt-in-an-rpm-world) detailing its use.

You'll need to install the [RepoForge repository](http://repoforge.org/use/) via `rpm` in order to be able to download the apt package. It's totally compatible, works and is supported... but also unnecessary, given that yum covers most needs.

Comment: I had apt before my reinstall. It worked perfectly fine, and I will not waste time having to figure out the respective names for each package I installed via apt for yum. I don't see why I shouldn't do it. Doesn't matter to me what package manager I use, I just want to use apt, and not yum.

Comment: Then why not just use Debian or a derivative?

Comment: @alexpja See my edited answer above.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that.

IIRC yum + apt won't cause issues being installed together, correct?

Comment: @alexpja Nope. No issues. It's not available in CentOS 6, though.

Comment: That's fine, using 5.9.

Comment: @alexpja You won't be using it forever. You'll have to learn `yum` eventually.

Comment: @MichaelHampton but at this moment I do not care about yum, I just need apt. I'll learn it when I'll need it.

Comment: @alexpja - seriously, you're swimming upstream here. You should either learn yum or switch to a Debian derivative.

Comment: @alexpja, if you're going to do this kind of thing at least make sure you document the steps so that you don't have to ask again.